# Steenrod Problem and realization of rational homology classes by manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Steenrod's  problem  asks wheter  a   simplicial homology  class  of  a  topological  space $x$, 
$$ x\in H_n(X, \mathbb{Z})$$ 
can be  represented  by a  triangulation  of  an  $n$-dimensional, closed  and  oriented  manifold.

It  is  known  that  if  $n\leq 6$,  then  all  classes  can  be  realized  by smooth manifolds, and  that  this  does  not  hold  in  higher  degrees.

Moreover,  in  dimensions  $2$  and  $1$, the  circle  and  the  orientable  surfaces  catch  all homology  classes.

Is  there  out  there  a  list  of orientable  smooth  3,4, 5  and  6- Manifolds  which  generate  the homology  groups  in the  relevant   degrees? 
What  about rational  coefficients?

Comment: This would be a long list, since for any closed oriented $n$-manifold $X$ the list would have to contain a closed oriented $n$-manifold $M$ with a degree $1$ map $f : M \to X$, and then $f_* : H_*(M) \to H_*(X)$ would have to be split surjective.